# Right Justification in Java

Tags: java

I've tried looking but I can't seem to find a solution to my justification problem. I want all the transaction amounts, which turn up with 2 decimals digits, to be all justified to the right, however, nothing I try seems to work. This is the result:

[image: Java dialog with unaligned numbers]

```
    Transaction temp;
    String message = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < checkAccnt.gettransCount(); i++)
    {
        temp = checkAccnt.getTrans(i);
        message += String.format("%-10d", temp.getTransNumber());
        message += String.format("%-10d", temp.getTransId());
        message += String.format("%10.2f", temp.getTransAmount()) + '\n';
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

Comment: It seems that you would have to alter the whitespace prior to the decimal number according to the length of the number. I'm quite sure how to do that with String.format though

Comment: Use constant width font.

Comment: What saka1029 said, and additionally: I guess you wouldn't even like right-justification, but an alignment of the `.` points (otherwise, if you had right-justified numbers like "1.11" and "1.99", the points would not align)

Comment: @Azulflame Any idea on how to do that by some other means?

Comment: @user3213337 I did some research and posted an answer. Could you try it out? And if you did, it was just updated.

Comment: @Marco13 How would I go about using "constant width font"? I'm just trying to follow the format posted in the sample run of my assignment. http://i.imgur.com/OW1pZqO.png

Comment: @user3213337 if you don't mind, could you edit the question to mention that it is homework, given it is an assignment?

Comment: Regarding the constant width font: `panel.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));`, also see related questions about "monospaced font" here on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to using a fixed width font (as suggested in the comments) or different widgets with better alignment control (as suggested in a different answer) might be to replace the space characters in front of the digits with space characters that have the same width as the digits (if the font has a fixed width for digits, which the screenshot seems to support):

```
message += String.format("%-10d", temp.getTransNumber()).replace(' ', '\u2007');
```

See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

It seems that JTable may be a better fit for what you are trying to do than just `String.format()`

```
int rows = checkAccnt.size(); // guess as to the appropriate method name, but you get the idea
int cols = 3;// based off of number of coloumns in the For statement

JTable table = new JTable(rows, cols);
DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer);

Transaction temp;
String message = "";
for (int i = 0; i < checkAccnt.gettransCount(); i++)
{
    temp = checkAccnt.getTrans(i);
    table.setValueAt(String.format("%-10d", temp.getTransNumber()), i, 0);
    table.setValueAt(String.format("%-10d", temp.getTransId()), i, 1);
    table.setValueAt(String.format("%10.2f", temp.getTransAmount()), i, 2);
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, table);
```

Comment: I can't really test it, as I don't have the whole of OP's code. But I'll edit accordingly

Comment: You shouldn't need to use spaces for padding if you're right-justifying a single column.